# How to apply javascript on asp.net button click?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap alert autocloseable msg. Code as follow

```
<div id="alertdiv" class="alert">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><span>' + message + '</span></div>
```

Asp.net Button click code

```
<div>
 <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="btn btn-block org" Style="margin-top: 0px" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" ValidationGroup="Login" OnClientClick="msg();" />
</div>
```

Javascript code as follow. Is javascript written is correct ? Please check it out!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        function msg() {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $(".alert").fadeTo(1500, 0).slideUp(500, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }, 5000);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: did you get an error?

Comment: No! , the script doesn't get fired@DyrandzFamador

Comment: try the example below @Rohan. it's an example of calling the javascript from asp button

Comment: Ok,wait for a sec!@DyrandzFamador

Comment: Compilation Error Msg : CS1002 ; expected at Sub btClick1(obj As Object, e As EventArgs) @Dyrandz

Answer (score 0):

```
function msg() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(1500, 0).slideUp(500, function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }, 5000);
}
```

You're declaring your function inside your ready. Declare it outside of it.

`$(document).ready(...);` basically says "when my document is finished rendering, run the code within." You don't want to do that, you just want to declare your function for use in your OnClientClick. If you move `msg()` out of the `.ready()`, it should work.

Also, ASP.NET controls render as regular html. I believe an `<asp:button>` renders as a regular button, if I'm not mistaken. You can use a delegated event handler like so:

```
$('#' + '<%= btnLogin.ClientID %>').on('click', function() {
    msg();
});
```

Comment: I cant understand the code $('#yourclientid').on('click', function(){
});. Would you please write in my code ? I'm an learner of asp & javascript .@Yatrix

Comment: I tried your updated code , it doesn't display msg function @Yatrix

Comment: @Rohan is it hitting the message function? Your comments above said msg() wasn't fire at all.

Comment: How to figure it out? Would you explain ! @Yatrix . Yes the msg() wasn't fired !

Comment: You have to learn how to debug JavaScript in the browser console. I can't explain that to you, that's something you have to learn to do. SO is here to help you answer certain questions, not teach you how to program. Just do some google searching and you should be able to learn everything you need to know for debugging .js.

Comment: Ok , i'll find out  And msg you after i figure out ! @Yatrix

Comment: I figure it from browser console , it doesn't call the msg() @Yatrix

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be of some help. I must confess that what you want to achieve is not clear to me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     myClosure=function() {
        var canyousee = "here I'm ";
        return (function () {
            return { canyouseeIt: function(){return confirm (canyousee)}};
        });
    }
</script>


<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="(myClosure())().canyouseeIt()" />
```

Comment: I want to achieve is the div tag , which is called through javascript with some time function in it, after some sec the div would fade out . This javascript is called through asp.net button click . @Shohel